# Check if someone is logged onto Facebook using mobile

Tags: facebook, mobile, login-script

I am developing an app only for mobile users. How could I check if a user is logged into Facebook using a mobile phone?

NOTE: If user is not logged in via mobile phone then content of the app should not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/) is a brief guide on how to implement SSO(Single-Sign-On) for mobile devices.